# Как объединить JS скрипты в один JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

помогите пожалуйста объединить эти 3 скрипта в один, спасибо.

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {$('#example002').dataTable({"pageLength": 5,"language": {"url": "/dataTables.russian.lang"}} );} );</script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {$('#example001').dataTable({"pageLength": 5,"language": {"url": "/dataTables.russian.lang"}} );} );</script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {$('#example').dataTable({"pageLength": 5,"language": {"url": "/dataTables.russian.lang"}} );} );</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#example002, #example001, #example')
       .dataTable({"pageLength": 5,"language": {"url": "/dataTables.russian.lang"}} );
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Arcadiy На здоровье. Успехов!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example002').dataTable({"pageLength": 5,"language": {"url": "/dataTables.russian.lang"}});
  $('#example001').dataTable({"pageLength": 5,"language": {"url": "/dataTables.russian.lang"}});
  $('#example').dataTable({"pageLength": 5,"language": {"url": "/dataTables.russian.lang"}});
} );</script>
```